# What is Bonnie Hopps referring to when she said Judy "opened their minds"?

Tags: zootopia

In Zootopia, the following dialogue occurs between Judy Hopps and her parents:

> *Judy Hopps*: ...and I made life so much worse for so many
>   innocent predators.
>
> *[A van horn sounds and a van pulls up]*
>
> *Stu Hopps*: Oh! Not all of them, though. Speak of the devil, Right on
>   time. *[The van has the words 'Gideon Grey's Real Good Baked Stuff with
>   Fresh Produce from Hopps' Family Farm' and Gideon Grey, grown up,
>   walks out of his van]*
>
> *Judy Hopps*: Is that... Gideon Grey?
>
> *Stu Hopps*: Yep! Sure it is. We work with him now.
>
> *Bonnie Hopps*: He's our partner, and we never would have considered it
>   had **you not opened our minds**.
>
> *Stu Hopps*: That's right, I mean Gid's turned into one of the top
>   pastry chefs in the Tri-Burrows.
>
> *Judy Hopps*: *[amazed]* That's... That's really cool, you guys.
>
> (Transcript from http://zootopia.wikia.com/wiki/Zootopia/Transcript)

A few scenes ago Judy made comments at a press conference which caused tension between predators and prey throughout the city of Zootopia. Surely if somehow Judy's parents heard about these comments or about the tension in Zootopia (it is a possibility they might already be aware, considering that Stu replied to Judy with *"Not all of them, though"* - his lack of confusion, surprise or any reaction while responding may show he understood what she was talking about), this whole business cooperation between Gideon Grey and Judy's parents would be out of the question.

So why are Gideon Grey and Judy's parents cooperating? What is Bonnie referring to?

**Edit:** A point has been brought up that my point about Judy's parents being aware of the situation in Zootopia or her comments is speculation. I agree, since it isn't explicitly mentioned in the film, so Judy's parents might not be aware at all of what happened in Zootopia. I only assumed so since...

1. ...Stu showed no sign of not understanding what Judy was talking about (i.e. he didn't show surprise or confusion, for instance)
2. ...Judy may have also told her parents what happened when she returned to Bunnyburrow. Wouldn't her parents wonder why she returned?

Therefore, I've included some stronger evidence near the beginning of the film, just before Judy departs for Zootopia:

> *Judy Hopps*: The only thing we have to fear is fear itself.
>
> *Stu Hopps*: And also bears. We have bears to fear too, say nothing of lions and wolves-
>
> *Bonnie Hopps*: Wolves?
>
> *Stu Hopps*: Weasels!
>
> *Bonnie Hopps*: You play cribbage with a weasel.
>
> *Stu Hopps*: Yeah, and he cheats like there's no tomorrow. *[Judy sighs.]* You know what? **Pretty much all predators**, and Zootopia's
>   full of 'em.
>
> *Bonnie Hopps*: Oh, Stu.
>
> *Stu Hopps*: And **foxes are the worst!**
>
> *Bonnie Hopps*: Actually, **your father does have a point there. It's in their biology. Remember what happened with Gideon Grey?**
>
> *Judy Hopps*: When I was nine. Gideon Grey was a jerk who happened to be a fox. I know plenty of bunnies who are jerks.
>
> *Stu Hopps*: Sure, yeah, we all do, absolutely. But just in case, *[holds up a bag]* we made a little care package to take with you.
>
> *Bonnie Hopps*: Mm-mm. I put some snacks in there.
>
> *Stu Hopps*: *[takes out a spray bottle]* This is **fox deterrent**.
>
> *Bonnie Hopps*: Yeah, that's safe to have.
>
> *Stu Hopps*: *[takes out a repellent]* This is **fox repellent**.
>
> *Bonnie Hopps*: Okay, the deterrent and the repellent, that's all she needs.
>
> *Stu Hopps*: *[takes out a fox taser]* Check this out! *[Stu turns the fox taser on. The fox taser releases a powerful blast, nearly zapping
>   Judy, who cringes.]*
>
> *Bonnie Hopps*: Oh, for goodness sake! *[pulls the fox taser away]* She has no need for a **fox taser**, Stu!
>
> *Stu Hopps*: Oh, come on, when is there not a need for a fox taser?

This dialogue shows:

1. Her parents are pretty much **set against all predators, particularly foxes**.
2. They're **aware of the incident** from Judy's childhood **involving Gideon Grey**.
3. Despite Judy making a point in defence of Gideon Grey, her parents **still seem insistent against foxes** (i.e. giving her "anti-fox tools", such as deterrent, repellent and a taser, specifically designed for use against foxes).

This seems to pile up even more evidence of how strange it seems that suddenly they move to form a business partnership with a **predator**? Who is a **fox**? Who **attacked their own daughter when she was a child**?

I mean, come on, surely it would take a miracle to restore neutral relations, let alone form a business partnership, with someone who seems to fit exactly what Judy's parents are afraid of?

Particularly against the backdrop of rising tension in Zootopia and Judy's comments, this business partnership seems almost irrational.

So, to reiterate again, what on earth could Bonnie Hopps possibly be referring to?

Comment: You assume they are aware of the situation in Zootopia. That may not be the case. And it is kind of an isolated case, only about a dozen animals in all of Zootopia.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths True, it's only a speculation I made, based on Stu's reaction, since it isn't explicitly mentioned in the film. Still, I've added some stronger evidence from near the beginning of the film, just before Judy leaves for Zootopia.

Answer (score 9):

This was actually made clearer in a deleted scene available on the Blu Ray. It happens when Nick and Judy are still investigating the case and she brings him to her apartment - where they suddenly meet her parents who came by for a surprise visit. When her parents are apprehensive about Nick, *Judy defends him, saying they've been working together and that he's actually her friend* - which Nick then proves by talking her up in front of them. You can see it here:

But to the movie's credit, there *is* a possible explanation even without this deleted scene. [According to the film's co-director Rich Moore](https://twitter.com/_rich_moore/status/729031671933075456?s=20), ***a couple of months have passed between the press conference and Judy quitting the force (and reconciling with Nick shortly after):***

> *From press conference to [Nick and Judy] making up it was about 2.5-3 months.*

And it's *during that time* that she could've called and talked to her parents, explained she was wrong to say all those things and told them about Nick. So it *is* plausible, it's just not clarified very well.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly the order of events was:

1. Judy opens her parent's minds about trusting all animals, even predators, and giving them chances.
2. Judy leaves for Zootopia.
3. Judy's parents partner with Gideon Grey.
4. The partnership goes well and Judy's parents come to trust Gideon Grey.
5. Judy makes her unfortunate comments at the press conference, which are not enough to shake their already firm relationship with Gideon Grey.

Comment: That seems possible, but then again the first point doesn't seem to fit into the film. Her parents seem quite set against predators **right up to the very last minute she leaves** (telling her she has to fear _"pretty much all predators"_, trying to give her anti-fox tools etc.)

Comment: Additionally, I'm just assuming her parents heard about her comments and/or the tension at Zootopia, since it isn't explicitly stated in the film. But if they did hear about either or both, then your fifth point may seem possible.

Comment: Between steps 2 and 3 there were likely also calls and/or letters home that included positive statements about predators in the city.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the mere example of herself, a bunny, taking a cop job is mind-opening in itself in the sense of not typecasting species by personality traits.